# C++ "oldstyle container ": pointer/ array/ new - possible missconception?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

Im just playing arround, just dont get why the first version works while the second one fails?

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int a,b;
    double d{3035.4534536};
    cout<<"Size of: int "<<sizeof (int)<<" double "<<sizeof (double)<<endl;

    a=*((int*)&d);
    b=((int*)&d)[1];
    int dd[2]; //{a,b};
    dd[0]=a; dd[1]=b;
    cout<<"a: "<<a<<" |b: "<<b<<endl;
    cout<<"d: "<<d<<" |: "<<*((double*)&dd)<<endl;

    // int  size=sizeof(d)/sizeof(int)+1, *temp= new int[size],
        // *f{(int*)(&d)}, *t{temp}, *s{t+size};
    // while(t!=s) { *t=*f; ++f; ++t; cout<<"."; }
    // cout<<"dOrig.: "<<d<<" |temp: "<<*((double*)&temp)<<endl;
    // delete[] temp;

    int size=sizeof(d)/sizeof(int)+1, *temp= new int[size];
    char *f{(char*)&d}, *t{(char*)temp}, *s{t+sizeof(d)};
    while(t!=s) { *t=*f; ++f; ++t; cout<<"."; }
    cout<<"dOrig.: "<<d<<" |temp: "<<*((double*)&temp)<<endl;
    delete[] temp;
}
```

...im aware that, "thats exactly WHY there are containers", it pure curiosity, and i just wanna understand whats the problem with the second?

Is there a conversion somewhere that im not aware of?
Or is the pointer thats returned by new-Statement more than a plain pointer to the first element?

Answer (score 1):

```
 a=*((int*)&d);
```

Is incorrect. When you do (int*), you use a reinterpret_cast.

`&d` is a pointer-to-double. You cannot convert a pointer-to-double to a pointer-to-int. Well, you can, but you cannot do the next operation, dereferencing it. As soon as you try to read the memory point to by `(int*)&d` as an integer, you get undefined behaviour.

What happens from there is, well, complex and undefined. Don't go there.

Comment: well, thats exactly where im trying to peek: <br/>if i understand correctly pointers are made up of an address and the cast-type(with its size). if i c-cast another pointer dont i just overwrite its type. Is there some conversion still happening?

Comment: @mcaustria the compiler is allowed to assume that changing an `int` cannot possibly change a `double`, it is allowed produce object code that relies on that assumption. What you *can* do is copy the bytes of a `double` into the bytes of some `int`s, because both are trivial types

Comment: I don't think a copy is allowed safely between type directly, unless you go through a char pointer. But one would have to check the pointer aliasing rules.

Comment: @Caleth theres nowhere a double assignment, i only a double cast, otherwise im working only with arrays in both cases, and they should be continues.

Comment: @Jeffry thats exactly what i tried in the second type. But the alignment may be a hint...was allready reading along...hehe

Comment: [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Strict_aliasing) ..whoever is interested ..so it should actually work if i use char-type or